# Iframe attack(xss) in sakai cle

Tags: java, security, xss, sakai

```
localhost:8080/portal/help/html/help.jsp?allowLink=true&emailLink='"()%26%251<iframe id="mainIframe" width="800" height="600" src="http://google.com"></iframe>
```

How to prevent cross site scripting  in sakai. i am calling req.getQueryString() in RequestFilter.java  then i am getting this url.please help me how to solve issue

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you uncover a security vulnerability in Sakai software please do not voice your concerns on any public listserv, blog or other open communication channel but instead notify the Sakai Foundation immediately at security@sakaifoundation.org. Please provide a callback telephone number so that we can contact you by telephone if it is deemed necessary.

See the policy here:
https://confluence.sakaiproject.org/display/SECWG/Security+Policy

If you create a login here:
https://jira.sakaiproject.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa

You can report the security issue by creating an issue and setting the Security Level pulldown to "Security Issue"
Thanks

Comment: Thanks azeckoski for your advice . i will mail you